# Windows 10 forgets sharing settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, network-drive

I have 2 computers with Windows 10 installed, and one of them has a shared drive that the other can access. The sharing works well. However, whenever I restart that computer, that drive is no longer shared. I can re-enable sharing and then it works, but I need to do it after every reboot.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** Someone asked how I enable sharing. I do it by right-clicking the drive in "This PC", Properties, Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing, Share this folder, then add permissions for everyone to edit.

Comment: How exactly are you mounting the shared volume?  Be as specific. [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  Include screenshots (English) if required.

Comment: Try in a Command Prompt run as Administrator to create the share using the command `net share sharename=path`.

Comment: @harrymc My user is already Administrator. I did try your command, didn't work.

Comment: You also need to set the security settings, as deatiled [in this article](https://pureinfotech.com/setup-network-file-sharing-windows-10/) in the section `Windows 10 file sharing using advanced settings`, from point 12 onwards. Also, you might want to check out the Section entitled `Share files over the network with no password on Windows 10`

Comment: Try also: (1) `net use <drive letter>: \\servername\sharename /persistent:yes`, (2) Restart the "Server" service and see if the shares come back. Question: Do the shares disappear from Explorer > Network, or do they become inaccessible?

Comment: Does the drive show sharing disabled after a reboot, or do you just need to re-add the permissions? Try running `Get-SmbShare | select Name,Path,ShareState,Special` in powershell (after sharing the drive, then again after rebooting), and check whether the share gets removed after reboot, or just set offline

Comment: When I go to Explorer > Network I get this error dialog: "Network discovery is turned off. Network computers and devices are not visible. Please turn on network discovery in Network and Sharing Center." This is despite the fact that I have other network drives working, so it doesn't seem to be preventing the use of network drives.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `net use` is for using a share, not serving a share. Did you mean I should do it from the computer I'm sharing from, or from the computer that's supposed to be accessing the share?

Comment: "Does the drive show sharing disabled after a reboot, or do you just need to re-add the permissions?" It shows sharing disabled.

Comment: I ran `Get-SmbShare | select Name,Path,ShareState,Special` after reboot and the share did not appear there.

Comment: Does restarting the "Server" service change anything?

Comment: I restarted it earlier and it didn't.

Comment: Could you try sharing just a folder instead of the whole C drive to see if that stays working after a reboot. Windows does an 'admin share' of the c drive by default so I'm wondering if your share it conflicting or something

Comment: I saw this might happen due to encrypted drive ( at the time of the boot ). Try to share from an unencrypted drive and see the results? Also, try to restart "server" service ( not just making sure it's running - but restart, and see if the shares are coming back up )

Answer (score 0):

Check the Startup Type of the "Server" service in services. Should be set to Automatic.

Comment: That service is set to Automatic and it's currently running, yet the problem remains.